# How to get binary data from boost::asio::streambuf

Tags: boost, boost-asio

How can I flush data from streambuf to file?
I've tried

```
read(*socket_, streamBuf, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(694784))
std::istream is(&streamBuf);
std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("test.exe");
is >> outfile;
outfile.close()
```

but that didn't work.
Any clue how to do that?

Comment: Can you give details on why it didn't work? exception, crash, no data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try a [`buffer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer/buffer_cast.html). Here is an example:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
size_t bytes = read( *socket_, buf, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(694784) );
buf.commit( bytes );

std::ofstream outfile( "test.exe" );
outfile << boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>( buf.data() );
```

Comment: Note that such a particular use of buffer_cast<>() on streambuf::data() is _not_ documented and the only reason it works is thanks to streambuf::const_buffers_type being currently implemented using const_buffers_1, which in addition to implementing the required ConstBufferSequence concept, also implements the ConvertibleToConstBuffer concept (as a side effect of const_buffers_1 being the adapter of const_buffer). Of course, it's _currently_ safe to use, but streambuf might be reimplemented in the future in a way which makes data() and prepare() return a buffer list instead of a single buffer.

Comment: @MichalWrobel which of course, it is implemented this way now. Returns iterators. Thanks for the comment.